# How to hide header on scroll in ionic 4?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I wanted to know how I can hide a header in Ionic 4 by scrolling down the page, and re-show it when scrolling up.

I found many solutions on how to do that, but they all turned out to not working or being out-of-date.

So I collected all piece of information I could find to provide this answer.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Thanks to [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rS5EYgFD2Kw) I got it to work.

First of all call `ionic g directive directives/hide-header`. You can of course replace `directive/hide-header` with your own path and name.

`hide-header.directive.ts`

```js
import { Directive, HostListener, Input, OnInit, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';
import { DomController } from '@ionic/angular';

@Directive({
    selector: '[appHideHeader]'
})
export class HideHeaderDirective implements OnInit {

    @Input('header') header: any;

    private lastY = 0;

    constructor(
        private renderer: Renderer2,
        private domCtrl: DomController
    ) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.header = this.header.el;
        this.domCtrl.write(() => {
            this.renderer.setStyle(this.header, 'transition', 'margin-top 700ms');
        });
    }

    @HostListener('ionScroll', ['$event']) onContentScroll($event: any) {
        if ($event.detail.scrollTop > this.lastY) {
            this.domCtrl.write(() => {
                this.renderer.setStyle(this.header, 'margin-top', `-${ this.header.clientHeight }px`);
            });
        } else {
            this.domCtrl.write(() => {
                this.renderer.setStyle(this.header, 'margin-top', '0');
            });
        }

        this.lastY = $event.detail.scrollTop;
    }

}
```

After that, in your template:

```html
<ion-header #header>
    <ion-toolbar><ion-title>Test</ion-title></ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content scrollEvents="true" appHideHeader [header]="header">
</ion-content>
```

Take care of the `scrollEvents`, `appHideHeader` and the `[header]` attributes! The last one takes the header element as argument, in this case `#header`.

---

Most of the code is the same as shown in the video. I changed the `host`-property from the `@Directive` and used the more up-to-date [HostListener](https://angular.io/api/core/HostListener).

If you want to use the directive in more than one directive, you need to create a [SharedModule](https://angular.io/guide/sharing-ngmodules).

To do so, create the module with `ng g module shared`. After that, add the `HideHeaderDirective` to the `declarations` and the `exports` array.

`shared.module.ts`

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { HideHeaderDirective } from './directives/hide-header.directive';


@NgModule({
    declarations: [HideHeaderDirective],
    exports: [HideHeaderDirective],
    imports: [
        CommonModule
    ]
})
export class SharedModule {}
```

Now add the shared module to all the modules you want to use the directive in.

> Note: You cannot import the directive in `app.module.ts` and use it in a submodule! You have to import the shared module in every direct module you want to use the directive in.

My current versions of `node`, `npm` and `ionic`:

[image: versions]

Comment: the header keeps flickering some of the time

Comment: did you find the soluation for this flickering issue? @MD.IBRAHIMKHALILTANIM

Comment: I extended this to include an additional input property `scrollThreshold` ("Minimum scroll offset from top in pixels until the animation kicks in.") that I set only on iOS to avoid issues with bouncing scroll in and in combination with the `ion-refresher`. It can be found here: https://gist.github.com/klemensz/2a91bbe764bf4b0046b47840b6bef429 Usage example: `<ion-content scrollEvents="true" appHideHeader [header]="segmentedSwitch" [scrollThreshold]="plt.is('ios') ? 50 : 0">`.

Comment: Thank you @KlemensZleptnig for the updated code. that worked for me since in iOS the header gets hidden after ion-refresher kicks in. Thank you for sharing.

Comment: Flickering can occur when adding new content because any negative Y event draws the header again.  To resolve this, I used the deltaY stuff to monitor changes

`if ($event.detail.deltaY > 50) `

and

`else if ($event.detail.scrollTop < 100 || $event.detail.deltaY < -50)`

Answer (score 1):

For this you can just place the ion-header before the ion-content. this is the simple answer for that.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer on how to improve your answer.