# Ionic 4 Hide/Show Header Directive Animation LAGS while scrolling

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, animation, ionic4, lag

I have been looking and searching for a good way to hide and show header on ionic 4 project while scrolling.
I have achieved that by the help of others on form and by doing some search, but what I am having issue now is that it is so laggy, like it flickers and something like that when it hides/shows.

For this i have used a directive.
Here is my ionic info:

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 5.4.9 (C:\Users\Milot\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.9.1
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.803.23
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 8.1.3
   @angular/cli                  : 8.1.3
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.0.0

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : android 8.1.0
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.3, (and 10 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res : 0.8.1 (update available: 0.9.0)
   native-run  : 0.2.9 (update available: 0.3.0)

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (C:\Users\Milot\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk)
   NodeJS            : v13.2.0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm               : 6.13.1
   OS                : Windows 10
```

And this is how i have used the directive:

```
import { Directive, Input, ElementRef, Renderer2, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { DomController } from "@ionic/angular";
​
@Directive({
  selector: "[myScrollVanish]"
})
export class ScrollVanishDirective implements OnInit {
  @Input("myScrollVanish") scrollArea;
​
  private hidden: boolean = false;
  private triggerDistance: number = 1;
​
  constructor(
    private element: ElementRef,
    private renderer: Renderer2,
    private domCtrl: DomController
  ) {}
​
  ngOnInit() {
    this.initStyles();
​
    this.scrollArea.ionScroll.subscribe(scrollEvent => {
      let delta = scrollEvent.detail.deltaY;
​
      if (scrollEvent.detail.currentY === 0 && this.hidden) {
        this.show();
      } else if (!this.hidden && delta > this.triggerDistance) {
        this.hide();
      } else if (this.hidden && delta < -this.triggerDistance) {
        this.show();
      }
    });
  }
​
  initStyles() {
    this.domCtrl.write(() => {
      this.renderer.setStyle(
        this.element.nativeElement,
        "transition",
        "0.1s linear"
      );
      this.renderer.setStyle(this.element.nativeElement, "height", "52px");
    });
  }
​
  hide() {
    this.domCtrl.write(() => {
    //   this.renderer.setStyle(this.element.nativeElement, "min-height", "0px");
      this.renderer.setStyle(this.element.nativeElement, "height", "0px");
    //   this.renderer.setStyle(this.element.nativeElement, "opacity", "0");
    //   this.renderer.setStyle(this.element.nativeElement, "padding", "0");
    });
​
    this.hidden = true;
  }
​
  show() {
    this.domCtrl.write(() => {
      this.renderer.setStyle(this.element.nativeElement, "height", "52px");
    //   this.renderer.removeStyle(this.element.nativeElement, "opacity");
    //   this.renderer.removeStyle(this.element.nativeElement, "min-height");
    //   this.renderer.removeStyle(this.element.nativeElement, "padding");
    });
​
    this.hidden = false;
  }
}
```

html file:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar [myScrollVanish]="scrollArea">
  </ion-toolbar >
</ion-header>
<ion-content #scrollArea scrollEvents="true"> ... </ion-content>
```

and here is a video of it, first time its with 0.1s linear and second time is with 0.5s linear:

[Click here to see streamable video](https://streamable.com/zqp3y)

i have tried these but with same results:

[Link 1](https://www.joshmorony.com/creating-a-custom-scroll-vanish-directive-with-ionic-web-components/)

[Link 2](https://medium.com/codechintan/ionic-hide-header-on-scroll-b8828a7a7f86)

[Link 3](https://github.com/heidji/ionic4-hidenav)

Comment: I've found this version works much better: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56996294/how-to-hide-header-on-scroll-in-ionic-4

Comment: @MikeRandall it even bounces much more, sometimes it bounces back with little scroll it hides and it comes back... check it here: https://streamable.com/j3jzl

Answer (score 0):

I made my custom show/hide header-footer scroll, no lagging or flickering anymore
Cheerss!!

```js
 private lastY = 0;
  logScrolling(event){
      // Hide Header on on scroll down
      // console.log(event.detail);
    
      if (event.detail.scrollTop > this.lastY) {
        console.log(this.header);
        document. querySelector(".header").classList.remove('nav-down');
        document. querySelector(".header").classList.add('nav-up');

        document. querySelector(".footer").classList.remove('footer-up');
        document. querySelector(".footer").classList.add('footer-down');
      }else {
        document. querySelector(".header").classList.remove('nav-up');
        document. querySelector(".header").classList.add('nav-down');

        document. querySelector(".footer").classList.remove('footer-down');
        document. querySelector(".footer").classList.add('footer-up');
      }
  
      this.lastY = event.detail.scrollTop;
  }
```

```css
body {
    padding-top: 40px;
}

header {
    background: #f5b335;
    height: 40px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    transition: top 0.2s ease-in-out;
    width: 100%;
}

.nav-up {
    top: -40px;
}

main {
   background:url(
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAAKCAYAAACNMs+9AAAAPklEQVQYV2O8dOnSfwYg0NPTYwTRuAAj0QqxmYBNM1briFaIzRbi3UiRZ75uNgUHGbfvabgfsHqGaIXYPAMAD8wgC/DOrZ4AAAAASUVORK5CYII=
   ) repeat;
    height: 2000px;
}

footer { 
    background: #ddd;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    transition: bottom 0.2s ease;
}

.footer-down{
    bottom: -40px;
}
* { color: transparent}
```

```html
<ion-content (ionScroll)="logScrolling($event)" #content id="ion-content" scrollEvents="true">
  <header id="header" class="nav-down header">
    This is your menu.
  </header>
  <main>
    This is your body.
  </main>
  <footer id="footer" class="footer">
    This is your footer.
  </footer>
</ion-content>
```