# Ionic how to align ion-content to bottom of page

Tags: css, angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm trying to align a message input box to the bottom of the page, but I can't seem to get it working. I've tried using align-self-end and making a css class for ion-footer.

```
<ion-content>
<ion-footer align-self-end>
  <ion-toolbar color="light">
    <ion-row align-self-end>
      <ion-col size="10">
        <ion-textarea auto-grow class="message-input" rows="1" [(ngModel)]="message"></ion-textarea>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col size="2">
        <ion-button expand="block" fill="clear" color="primary" [disabled]="message === ''" class="msg-btn"
          (click)="sendMessage()">
          <ion-icon name="paper-plane"></ion-icon>
        </ion-button>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-footer> 
</ion-content>
```

```
ion-footer{
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
    margin: auto; 
    padding-top: .5em;
    padding-bottom: .5em;
  }
```

Comment: What is the ionic version ?

Comment: Version CLI 4.12.0

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`<ion-footer>` is not meant to go inside `<ion-content>`

The structure of html file should be

```
<ion-header>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
</ion-content>

<ion-footer>
</ion-footer>
```

In your case you want to show another element towards the bottom of the content, you can insert textarea like this..Do not put ion-row inside the ion-toolbar.

```
<ion-content>
</ion-content>


<ion-footer>
    <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-textarea maxRows="4" [(ngModel)]="message" placeholder="Write a message"></ion-textarea>
        <ion-icon name="paper-plane" slot="end"></ion-icon>
    </ion-toolbar>
</ion-footer>
```

Comment: When setting up the page like this, I notice that the footer and header are ALWAYS showing. I want the content to scroll up and down to hide the footer and header as I scroll the content. It looks like Ionic forces the developer to have the header and footer constantly visible. Am I incorrect on this? I can't discern how to solve the problem. I'd rather have the content scroll all the way down before the footer shows.

Comment: you can skip the header and footer by implementing `ion-toolbar` inside your `ion-content`. But the view will interfere with device notches.
If you want to dynamically hide header footer, check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/56996295/5379936 and this https://www.joshmorony.com/creating-a-custom-scroll-vanish-directive-with-ionic-web-components/

Answer (score 1):

another method would be

```
.support{
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  bottom: 20px;
  width: 100%;
}

<ion-content padding>
  
  ... other elements

  <div class="support">
     <p>some text</p>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```